# Render Json data in partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am currently working on a shopping cart application using MVC5 and have a requirement to allow editing of the cart which is displayed as a partial view in a jQuery UI dialog.

I have added a javascript method to allow an ajax call to the controller however I am having an issue with the display of the json result data.  At the moment it is rendering as a blank page even though the json data is valid.

The jquery code is as follows:

```
$(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
        // Get the id from the link
        var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("cartid");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/",
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: {
                id: recordToDelete
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#shoppingcart").html(data);                    
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorstring) {
                alert("There has been an error textStatus: [" + textStatus + "] \r\n errorstring: [" + errorstring + "]");
            }
        })
    });
```

I have attempted to display the data manually and this works successfully however I was hoping I could do it using my partial view as it stands.

Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have your RemoveFromShoppingCart Controller return the partial view you want updated (bound with the updated model). Then in Jquery simply update the section that shows the partial view with the updated Partial View.

I am assuming that in your current code sample data is a JSON object that is coming back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the required return type:

if you want JSON, specify:

```
datatype: 'json',
```

As your code seems to want HTML and not JSON, **do not return a JSON result.**

*Please also show your controller action method*